# W3 CSS Validation error Parse error

Tags: html, css

When I try validating the following code:

```
   .cd-stretchy-nav ul a { (line 186)
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 calc(1em + 60px) 0 1em;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 1rem;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s;
    transition: color 0.2s;
}

    .cd-stretchy-nav ul a::after { (line 200)
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    right: 22px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
}
```

I get these errors.

**191** .cd-stretchy-nav ul a   Parse Error calc(1em + 60px) 0 1em;

**200**     Parse Error [: white; opacity: 1; font-size: 1rem; -webkit-transition: color 0.2s; -moz-transition: color 0.2s; transition: color 0.2s; } .cd-stretchy-nav ul a::after]

What exactly is causing these errors? code works fine in website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a bug in the CSS3 validation service provided by W3C. See https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=18913 for more information.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your CSS `calc` value and the second error is likely a result of the false-negative response from that service.